# what happens when i only call a constructor?

Tags: c++

This may sound naive. I want to know what happens when i explicitly call a constructor like this:

```
class A{
/*...*/
  public:
    A(){}
};
int main(){
  A();
  return 0;
}
```

Is a useless object created which remains in the memory until the scope of main() ends?

Comment: just add `cout <<` in ctor and dtor and you will see it for yourself

Comment: Do what Gene said, then call the constructor again on the next line, that's how you will see what's going on.  If you created two objects normally (as l-values), you would see ctor-ctor-dtor-dtor, but creating nameless objects like this (r-values) you will see ctor-dtor-ctor-dtor.

Answer (score 3):

You create an object that lasts until the end of the statement.

Comment: So during runtime, A() will create an object and destroy it before proceeding forward?

Comment: which in this case compiler will optimize away, leaving only `return 0;`

Comment: @Abhi Yes. That kind of object is otherwise called an rvalue.

Comment: @Gene: how can you tell without knowing what is inside the dots?

Comment: @Gene: Its not allowed to optimize it away. The constructor/destructor may have side affects the developer wants. Copy elision is about the only way to remove a potential object and that only happens when the copy constructor could have been called.

Answer (score 2):

Its considered a nameless temporary which gets destroyed after the end of the full expression.  In this case, the point right after the semicolon.  To prove this, create a destructor with a print statement.

Answer (score 2):

> when i explicitly call a constructor like this

You are not calling a constructor here; but creating a temporary object which gets destructed immediately. Constructor can be called explicitly with an object of that type (which is not advisable).

> Is a useless object created which remains in the memory until the
>   scope of main() ends?

It doesn't have scope till the function ends, but till the `;` ends.

Comment: "It doesn't have scope till the function ends, but till the ;  ends." Beg to differ but the scope of the temporary object created will have the scope for the lifespan of stack-frame. So in above case, scope will be until the closing "}" is encountered by compiler for function main. That is because compiler will call the destructor only when it sees stack is gonna get unwind when } is met.

Comment: The above comment was for iammilind and i do not know why my @ is not working :(

Comment: @Viren, the scope of `A()` in this example only till the `;` ends and not the `main()`. see http://www.ideone.com/ebTHP

Comment: @Viren: The temporary object dies at the `;`.

Comment: @iammilind: He is calling the constructor. Part of the creation of the temporary object is to correctly call the constructor.

Comment: `when i` **explicitly** `call a constructor`. This is the part of his question. I have mentioned this in quotes, just skipped to mention in my answer because that's trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking you can never make a direct call to a constructor in C++. A constructor is called by the implementation when you cause an object of class type to be instantiated.

The statement `A();` is an expression statement and the expression is a degenerate form of an explicit type conversion (functional notation). `A` refers to the type, strictly speaking constructors don't have names.

From the standard (5.2.3 [expr.type.conv] / 2:

> The expression `T()`, where `T` is a simple-type-specifier for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualified) void type, creates an rvalue of the specified type, which is value-initialized [...].

Because your class type has a user-declared default constructor the value-initialization of this temporary will use this constructor. (see 8.5 [dcl.init]/5)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I re-visited temporary and found that in the above example, it's actually a part of expression that is initializing an object. So yes, the scope ends at ;

[Here:](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr382.htm)

When a temporary object is created to initialize a reference variable, the name of the temporary object has the same scope as that of the reference variable. When a temporary object is created during the evaluation of a full-expression (an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression), it is destroyed as the last step in its evaluation that lexically contains the point where it was created.